# Bizagi Studio/ BARuleCategory SQL

Tags: business-rules, bizagi

I have a Rule category called Radication Number in my database for the category of rules in Bizagi. What is the use of this type?

For the sake of curiosity, I want to know the importance and reason for the existence of this category.